# New object instance from static function

Tags: c#

I have this simple struct in a .cs file (which is part of a .dll project):

```
namespace SteelStructuresLibrary
{
    public struct myPoint
    {
        private double x;
        private double y;

        public double X { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
        public double Y { get { return y; } set { y = value; } }

        public myPoint(double x, double y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I a static class like this (in another .cs file -if this is of any value- of the same .dll project):

```
namespace SteelStructuresLibrary
{   
    public static class Geometry
    {
        public static myPoint? getIntersectingPoint(Cline line1,Cline line2)
        {
            //...some calculations of A1,B1 etc...
            if (det == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                myPoint IntersectingPoint=new myPoint (((B2 * C1 - B1 * C2) / det),((A1 * C2 - A2 * C1) / det));
                return IntersectingPoint;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns IntersectionPoint.
But then, I call this getIntersectingPoint function, in my program, no object is returned:

```
myPoint IntersPoint;
IntersPoint = (myPoint) Geometry.getIntersectingPoint(line1, line2);
```

In the debug process, the watch window says "The name 'IntersPoint' does not exist in the current context". What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the value of `det` when stepping into this method during debugging?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting into your else?

Comment: Can you show all the code for `getIntersectingPoint`?

Comment: Why are you putting logic like this in a separate util class? This code smells bad.

Comment: One wonders why you could not have shown an SSCCE and saved us from all the guesswork

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you are absolutely right. I was kind of desperate when i decided to make the post. Won't happen again. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying  - In the debug process, the watch window says "The name 'IntersPoint' does not exist in the current context". Are you sure you're in the right context? May be you did not hit the right closure? Where do you set your breakpoint?

May be at the breakpoint you hit IntersPoint is not defined. Add a breakpoint right on that line where IntersPoint gets assigned and see.

I copied your code and had no issues compiling it and running.

Comment: or maybe he set the breakpoint somewhere in the method *before* the line `myPoint IntersPoint`

Comment: yeah, that's what i meant. The context of the breakpoint that he's examining has no knowing of IntersPoint variable

Comment: @panos on the line `myPoint IntersPoint`? Because at that point, it still hasn't been defined/declared. The break happens before the line that the breakpoint is on is executed.

Comment: Right after that line, i get no result.

Comment: Found it. Sorry guys for bothering you. I was expecting while hoovering on `IntersPoint` to get something. I added a line using this `double tmp= IntersPoint.X;` and I got the result. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx). When you work with it you first have to check if it contains value. Only if it has value you can retrieve it.

```
myPoint? IntersPointNullable = Geometry.getIntersectingPoint(line1, line2);
if (IntersPointNullable.HasValue)
{
    myPoint IntersPoint= IntersPointNullable.Value;
}else{
    // no intersection
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not true. Casting it to `(myPoint)` will return the `Value`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You are right. Never noticed this. Fixed my answer.

Comment: I don't think the problem is on null. I erased it and still got the same problem.

Comment: @panos We are not your debuggers. Either post the WHOLE code or debug it yourself.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I thought that posting part of the code would be clearer for you to read.

Comment: We don't want to see all of your code. Just enough to demonstrate the issue. You need to learn about SSCCE.